# Kubernetes: When creating a new mutating webhook, how can I apply the mutation to existing resources in the cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

If I have an existing cluster with existing resources and I create a new mutating webhook that needs to patch resources (e.g., adding a label to a namespace), once I create the mutating webhook all future resources get modified, but the ones already existing in the cluster do not. What is the best way of passing off existing resources (e.g., kube-system namespace) to the mutating webhook to get patched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, you are not able to pass already deployed resources to [MutatingAdmissionWebhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#mutatingadmissionwebhook).

As an option that you most probably wont like, you can path [existing resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#patch).

In addition I would like to quote you [Avoiding operating on the kube-system namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#avoiding-operating-on-the-kube-system-namespace)  doc, as you mentioned  `kube-system` namespace:

> The `kube-system` namespace contains objects created by the Kubernetes
> system, e.g. service accounts for the control plane components, pods
> like `kube-dns`. Accidentally mutating or rejecting requests in the
> `kube-system` namespace may cause the control plane components to stop
> functioning or introduce unknown behavior. If your admission webhooks
> don't intend to modify the behavior of the Kubernetes control plane,
> exclude the `kube-system` namespace from being intercepted using a
> namespaceSelector.

Comment: Right, I mention kube-system specifically because I need to include labels on it (and other excluded namespaces) so that mutations from 3rd party libraries do not get applied to that namespace. The patch is applied by the webhook, so if it already exists, it's too late. My current conclusion is same as yours, I will have to list and patch the existing namespaces in a separate job.